# Wierd graphics issue in WoW

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, graphics, gaming

I noticed these weird transparent dot like things around various things in World of Warcraft when I started playing again recently. It doesn't look normal, nor was it there before and is quite distracting to me. Here is a screenshot, i outlined some of the places where I am noticing the problem.

[[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/goUG2.jpg]

<sup>click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goUG2.jpg)

Any idea what this could be?

Comment: Im not really seeing an issue to be honest...

Comment: You have to blow up the image to full size to see it

Comment: Im seeing the horizontal lines by some of it, is that hat you mean? Have you tried different graphics settings to see if they change or dissapear?

Comment: If it's appearing in a screenshot then it's not hardware related. I would assume it's just elements in the game's engine.